# How would I use AngularJS ng-repeat to repeat this structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would I use AngularJS ng-repeat to repeat this structure?

```
<div class=black></div>
<div class=white></div>
<div class=black></div>
<div class=white></div>
```

...etc(not wrap with tag)

Answer (score 7):

If you're iterating over an array of items and need alternating black/white backgrounds then you can do it like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class-odd="'black'" ng-class-even="'white'">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fNCnr/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="color in ['black','white']" class="{{color}}"></div>
```

Output:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in ['black','white']" class="black"></div>
<div ng-repeat="color in ['black','white']" class="white"></div>
```

Or (more verbose):

```
<div ng-repeat="color in ['black','white']" ng-class="color"></div>
```

Output:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in ['black','white']" ng-class="color" class="ng-scope black"></div>
<div ng-repeat="color in ['black','white']" ng-class="color" class="ng-scope white"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you also know how can I repeat this structure? <div class=black></div>& #32;

Comment: @Paul, how many times do you want to repeat it?  If it is a fixed number of times, then simply repeat the "'black','white'" in the array as asgoth shows in his answer.

Comment: Sorry... I have a problem with my inline-block elements. As you se there http://amiu.ru/sorax/ my lower elems are collapse because there are no gap or '/n' between them. I need to repeat thoose elements so there will be a gap or '/n' between them. In underscore template I just write "print('\n')"...

Comment: @Paul, I don't think there is a way to do this with ng-repeat.  You'll probably have to use CSS styling on the divs.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you define a list of colors:

```
$scope.colors = ['black', 'white', 'black', 'white', 'black', 'white', ...];
```

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in colors" ng-class="color"></div>
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/GKMuC/).